# ThreeJS : fit camera zoom according to a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, three.js

I just begin to learn Three js and I face to a problem when tryng to add a plane geometry based on a img tag on the dom.

**Context**

Here is my actuel html template :

```
<figure>
  <div class="aspect" />
  <img class="img" src="@/assets/images/project1.jpg" />
</figure>
```

The img tag is hidden by css property `display: none` and the `.aspect` div give the size of the element by receiving `width: 50vw` and `padding-top: 60%`

I calculate the width - height of the element by using `getBoundingClientRect` func and applying it to the plane geometry like that :

```
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(el.width, el.height, 5)
```

Then I simply apply the texture of my image to it

**My problem**

As you can see on the screenshots, the plane geometry has not the exact size of my aspect div (in red) :

[image]

[image]

For the moment I manually set the z axis of my camera, but I know it's not the good solution and just wanted to know if there was an existing solution to acheive this ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using an **OrthographicCamera**

Doc here :
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)